# escapeHtml="false" in ftl template throws argument type mismatch

Tags: java, html, struts2, freemarker

This is the code.

```
<@s.property value="content" escapeHtml="false"/>
```

variable content is retrieved from the database and contains a HTML fragment. If i remove the `escapeHtml` attribute the content is retrieved successfully and it is written on the screen. The content contains two images and without the `escapeHtml` attribute the screen prints the html content as a string representation. But i want to view the images in HTML. So i use `escapeHtml="false"` and an exception is thrown as i can see from the logs.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

What should i do to view the content as HTML?

Comment: Which version of S2 are you using? Old versions don't have `escapeHtml` attribute, but there was `escape` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly that should be `escapeHtml=false`, without the quotation marks. If you write `"false"`, that's a string in FreeMarker. (BTW, 2.3.22 explains this in the error message, so certainly you aren't using the latest version.)

Answer (score 0):

i used the same piece of code in a jsp. The code in the jsp is :
`<s:property value="content" escapeHtml="false"/>`. That worked properly. I guess it is a freemarker issue.